# Overflox-x doesn't work

Tags: html, css, overflow, fixed

Overflow-x doesn't work in my navigationbar. I don't know why this isn't working. http://www.danielvanlier.nl/projectrendionafmaken/

this is my code

HTML

```
<div class="navigationbar">
<div class="navigation-buttons">
  <button class="voordeel">uw voordeel      </button>
  <button class="bieden">wat bieden wij</button>
  <button class="wat">wat doen wij</button>
  <button class="wie">wie zijn wij</button>
  <button class="contact">contact      </button>
</div>
<div class="element logo"></div>
<div class="element background"></div>
```

CSS

```
.navigation-buttons {
 position: absolute;
 top: 18px;
 left: 29.9166666666%;
 z-index: 48;
 width: 824px;
 height: 38px;
 }

 .navigationbar {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 49;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 1200px;
 height: 75px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `position: absolute;` on your `.navigation-buttons` takes that block out of the normal page flow, and so its width is not actually contained within `navigationbar`, and so there is no overflow.

You might be able to remove the position:absolute and do something like setting a `margin-left: 29.9%` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a scroll bar for your header then the problem is currently your width on your nav buttons is set to 800px and they are not exceeding that width.

If you set the width on the buttons to smaller than their current collective bounding box width then you will get a scroll bar with your current code.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/vZ7zZ/

HTML

```
<div class="navigationbar">
<div class="navigation-buttons">
  <button class="voordeel">uw voordeel      </button>
  <button class="bieden">wat bieden wij</button>
  <button class="wat">wat doen wij</button>
  <button class="wie">wie zijn wij</button>
  <button class="contact">contact      </button>
</div>
<div class="element logo"></div>
<div class="element background"></div>
```

CSS

```
.navigation-buttons {
   position: absolute;
   top: 18px;
   left: 29.9166666666%;
   z-index: 48;
   width: 100%;
   height: 38px;
 }


.navigationbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 49;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1200px;
  height: 75px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```